# Django makemigration does not detect my models

Tags: python, json, django

I have the following structure :

```
DjangoProjectRoot
    API
      Peak
         peak_model.py
      Waterfall
         waterfall_model.py
    models.py
      ...
```

As you can sea I organized the code to have separate module for each models, containing the model itself as well as the associated serializer and view.

When I delete my database schema, all the migrations "makemigrations", the others tables are created, except the waterfall one.

```
  api/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Book
    - Create model Department
    - Create model Natural
    - Create model Publisher
    - Create model Region
    - Create model Cave
    - Create model Glacier
    - Create model Lake
    - Create model Peak
    - Create model Saddle
    - Create model Shelter
    - Create model Municipality
    - Create model Guide
    - Add field region to department
    - Create model Collection
    - Create model Author
```

Any idea why ?

I just refactored my code, before everything was in the model field. I'm also a bit surpised by "     - Add field region to department  ". My database is empty and I cleaned the migrations. Maybe I should add something in the ***init.py*** file ? Seems like django needs to detect my new structure ?

waterfall_model.py :

```
from django.db import models
from api.natural.natural_model import Natural
class Waterfall(Natural):
    height = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 1):

you should register your apps in `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'API.Peak',
    'API.Waterfall'
    ...
]
```

also don't forget to rename `peak_model.py` and `waterfall_model.py` into `modes.py` or organize they in `models` module.

Comment: Effictively, the apps were not registered. I did it, but it deleted all the table during migration. Any idea why ? Also I tried to rename as you proposed, but it doesn't change anything. Can you explain why you asked me to rename the files ?

Comment: by default django takes registered folder as an App, and takes file "models.py" as a source for your Models. If you named models file as a "models_sourse_file" - django can not find any Models automatically. You can change this behaviour, but why? Simply change file name to models.py and enjoy. Other possibility - to create models folder and put all model files into it, and after you should register every file with models in _ _ ini _ _.py as import: from .peak_model import *. The model tables are deleted, if django think - the model for table not more exists.

Answer (score 0):

When making migrations, Django goes through all the apps listed in the `INSTALLED_APPS`, looks at existing migrations to build the migration state, and then compares that to the current status of the models that are available in apps' `models` module.

In order to have them recognized, you'll either need to have them all in `models.py`, or, if you're going with a package (`models/` dir with multiple files), you'll need to import them all in the `models/__init__.py` file.

When there is already a `migrations/` package present in app's dir, `makemigrations` will just pick the models up and generate the new migrations. However, if you do not have a `migrations` package, Django will not pick it up automatically, and you will have to explicitly specify the apps' names.

e.g. If you have an `API.Peak` app installed, but you do not have a `API/Peak/migrations/` folder present, you will have to explicitly provide it, i.e. `python manage.py makemigrations Peak` (Note that when apps have dots in them, you only need to specify the last part, so `API.Peak` and `API.Waterfall` would be designated just with `Peak`, or `Waterfall`)

---

**tl;dr** As Maxim Danilov instructed, you'll need to add those apps into the `INSTALLED_APPS`, make sure you have an importable `models` module that contains those modules, and then run `makemigrations` command again (explicitly specifying app name might be required).